# How to fill a large gap between tile and shower tub to ensure waterproof gap

Tags: shower, floor, caulk

I incorrectly tiled my bathroom walls, leaving a 3/8 inch gap between the subway tiles and the shower floor tub.
[image]

I have purchased some back rod roll to help with caulk fill. 
Before I put all this together, I have a few questions:

1. Do i need to prepare anything before I install this rod?
2. There are two drainage grooves - I have read that tiles are actually not waterproof and they sweat. This sweat drains down behind the tiles and runs along the shower tub lip and out on these grooves. I dont want to jam up anything or restrict water flow with these rods. Should I leave a gap? I'm concerned with a gap that water will get into the drywall[image]
3. I assume I should lay the rod before grouting..? Ot not?
4. I know I'm an idiot for leaving such a large gap. Actually for following wrong advice, i.e. for drainage - we has really bad mold. Am I good with above approach as I really dont want to pull all the tiles off and reinstall drywall?
   Any other warnings/advice would be appreciated to make sure this doesn't leak into my lounge below me.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the plan is sound. The only think I would change is that I would use Caulk to glue "A" in (to the left site of "A"). This gives you double protection.

This kind of shit happens to everybody, don't worry.

Good Luck